# Excel VBA: Fill.UserPicture

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

At `cell.Comment.ShapeRange...` I get an error: "Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". What is wrong with it?

`Cells(cell.Row, 6)` is the reference column that contains the urls for the images. E.g. `http://somelink.com/img.jpg`

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range


Set rng = Range("B2:B2331")


For Each cell In rng.Cells
    cell.AddComment
    cell.Comment.Text Text:="Owner:" & Chr(10) & ""
    cell.Comment.ShapeRange.Fill.UserPicture Cells(cell.Row, 6).Value
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a shape somewhere?

Comment: @Raystafarian the comment is the shape.. or no?

Comment: I don't think `.shaperange` is a property or method of `comment`

Comment: Well, I've tried just "Shape" which is a property and still get an error.

Answer (score 1):

First, `.shaperange` isn't a property or method of `comment` so you can't use that.

Here's an example that would work -

```
Sub tete()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 6)
rng.AddComment
rng.Comment.Text Text:="hi"
rng.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture ("C:\Users\path\to\pic.jpg")
End Sub
```

Which brings us to the usage of `.UserPicture()` that requires a path as string. So if your path is in that cell, make sure you're taking the value of it.

So if cell G1 = `C:\Users\path\to\pic.jpg`

```
rng.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture (Range("G1"))
```

would work.

---

*This is an edit by [historystamp](https://superuser.com/users/263831/historystamp) that I'm allowing because it doesn't alter the original intent of the answer and because it is based heavily upon it, it may not do too well or have visibility as a new answer.*

This version worked in macOS 10.10.5 with Excel 2011.

```
Sub tete()
' Raystafarian
'    https://superuser.com/a/1011255/2638314

' This is the shortest code I have seen for inserting a picture into
'   a commnet.  & It works.

Dim rng As Range
Dim aPicture As String
Debug.Print "-------------------------- " & Now
aPicture = "Macintosh SSD:Users:mac:Desktop:numbers:1.png"
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 8)
rng.AddComment
rng.Comment.Text Text:=" "
Debug.Print aPicture
rng.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture (aPicture)
End Sub
```

Comment: Well with my example, I've used the Shape property and I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to surround your string with `()` for it to be an argument of `userpicture`

Comment: yes I have () around Cells(cell.Row, 6).Value and still get the error.

Comment: So what's in that cell?

Comment: I have a http://url.com/image.jpg link. I believe I fixed it. I had the range filtered. Unfiltering it made it work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I been looking all over the Internet for excel macro code to insert a picture into a comment on a 2011 macOS excel sheet. This one works and is short!  The others were much longer and I could not get them to work.